# What is the relationship between the equation of combinatorial species $L=1+XL$ and the similar one of data types, and how could it be generalized

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, combinatorial-species

In several places (for example [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11580.pdf)) I have seen a comparison made between

- The equation of combinatorial species $L = 1 + XL$ where $L$ is the species of linear orders and $X$ is the species of "elements"
- The equation of algebraic data types $L(x) = 1 + x L(x)$ where $L(x)$ is the type of lists of elements of the type $x$

However, I don't understand the comparison, because:

- The concept of a linear order on a set is completely different than the concept of a list of elements of a set. A list is allowed to be any length, have duplicates, etc. But a linear order on $S$ must be the same length as $S$ and must list each element once.
- The addition and multiplication operations on combinatorial species seem completely different in nature to those operations as they are defined on algebraic data types. For example, the "$x L(x)$" in the equation of data types means "an element of a set and a list of elements of the same set", whereas the "$XL$" in in the equation of species means "first partition a set into two sets and then do two different things with the two different sets".
- The analogy doesn't seem to extend to other equations of species. For example, the same document I linked to above gives the example of $S = E \cdot \mathrm{Der}$ where $S$ is the species of permutations, $E$ is the species of "sets", and $\mathrm{Der}$ the species of "derangements". But there doesn't seem to be any way to interpret that as a corresponding identity of data types, as far as I can tell. For example, it could be interpreted as "to pick a permutation on a set, first pick [something] and then pick a a derangement on the set", but there is no "[something]" that would make that sentence true.

So my question is, what is the actual connection between these equations, and how would it generalize to other equations of species?

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is that linear orders are isomorphic to lists of elements of type $1$ (the type which has a single element). The "set" in "linear order on a set" and "list of elements of a set" are two different sets. It is the simplest possible comparison: there is a unique linear order of size $n$, and it corresponds to the unique list of $n$ identical things.